# Same iframe in two places on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a strange problem.
I've created an iframe on the page and now want to put it inside of two different holders:

```
 var iFrame = $('[data-id="loginWindowIframe"]');

    //put the iframe in first holder
    $('#loginWindow').html(iFrame);

    //put the iframe to the second holder
    $('[data-id="loginWindow"]').html(iFrame);
```

The problem is that iframe is being completely removed from the first holder, when I add it to the second one. Seems like I can have only one instance of iframe with same attributes on the page...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just moving it around. Clone it

```
var $iFrame = $('[data-id="loginWindowIframe"]');

//put the iframe in first holder
$('#loginWindow').empty().append($iFrame);

//put a clone of the iframe to the second holder
$('[data-id="loginWindow"]').empty().append($iFrame.clone());
```

Please note I've used `$iFrame` instead of `iFrame`. This is purely for readability - it signifies it holds a jQuery object.

Comment: thanks! but why r you using .empty().append() instead of .html()? Is there something different?

Comment: It's the correct approach. `html()` is used when you insert a string of html not a jQuery object. I wouldn't have thought your usage of it actually worked.

Comment: why I.m asking - is that I've looked throught .html() method - it completely removes innerHtml and clears memory (listeners) - so basically does the same as .empty()

Comment: Ok. Just to clarify on the original problem, when you select an element with jQuery, you're not creating another version in the variable, and when you use it, you're not creating other versions -  the assigned variable IS (as good as) the DOM element.